# How can i make a drop down box show different characters

Tags: windows, cpu-word

how can i make a drop down box show a list of options but only show one character when closed

for example

the drop down box would show

A horse 
B cat 
C dog
D fish

and when the drop down box is closed  all that would show is the first character.

any help would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<select
    style="width:40px;"
    onblur="this.style.width='40px';"
    onfocus="this.style.width='auto';"
    onChange="this.style.width='40px';"
>
    <option>A Cat</option>
    <option>B Dog</option>
    <option>C Horse</option>
    <option>D Hippopotamus</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VGfgW/